# nanoflann kdtree adaptor raises segfault

Tags: c++, flann

I am trying to use nanoflann's kdtree structure in a class of mine. I have the following header for a kdtree adaptor, which is only a small (possibly bad) variation of [this](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann/blob/master/examples/KDTreeVectorOfVectorsAdaptor.h), supposed to allow a kd-tree structure with 3d vectors as elements:

```
// "KdVec3dAdaptor.h"
#include "nanoflann.hpp"
#include <vector>


using Distance = nanoflann::metric_L2;  // Was in template before, dont need it, this way its easier to read
using VectorOfVectorsType = std::vector<std::array<double,3>>;

template <class VectorOfVectorsType>
struct KdVec3dAdaptor
{
    typedef KdVec3dAdaptor<VectorOfVectorsType> self_t;
    typedef typename Distance::template traits<double,self_t>::distance_t metric_t;
    typedef nanoflann::KDTreeSingleIndexAdaptor< metric_t,self_t,3,size_t>  index_t;

    VectorOfVectorsType m_data; 
    index_t* index; //! The kd-tree index for the user to call its methods as usual with any other FLANN index.

    KdVec3dAdaptor() = default;

    KdVec3dAdaptor(const VectorOfVectorsType &mat, const int leaf_max_size = 10) : m_data(mat)
    {
        const size_t dims = mat[0].size();
        index = new index_t( dims, *this /* adaptor */, nanoflann::KDTreeSingleIndexAdaptorParams(leaf_max_size ) );
        index->buildIndex();
    }

    ~KdVec3dAdaptor()
    { // destructor
        delete index;
    }

    KdVec3dAdaptor& operator=(KdVec3dAdaptor&& other)
    {  // move assignment operator
        if (this != &other)
        {  // check that no self-assignment is performed
            delete index;
            index = other.index;
            m_data = other.m_data;
            other.index = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    const self_t & derived() const
    {
        return *this;
    }
    self_t & derived()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    inline size_t kdtree_get_point_count() const
    {// Must return the number of data points
        return m_data.size();
    }

    inline double kdtree_get_pt(const size_t idx, int dim) const
    { // Returns the dim'th component of the idx'th point in the class
        return m_data[idx][dim];
    }

    template <class BBOX>
    bool kdtree_get_bbox(BBOX & /*bb*/) const
    { // return false to default to a standard bbox computation loop.
        return false;
    }
};
```

The problem I am facing is using this kdtree structure as a member variable of a class. A minimal version of that class with the needed type definitions would be:

```
// "test.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include "KdVec3dAdaptor.h"

const int dimens = 3;
using vec3d = std::array<double, dimens>;
using vec_arr =  std::vector<vec3d>;
using my_kd_tree =  KdVec3dAdaptor<vec_arr>;

class foo
{
public:
    const int n;
    const double level;
    my_kd_tree init_ps_tree;

    foo(const int &N, const double &level, vec_arr &kset)
    :n(N), level(level)
    {
        init_ps_tree = my_kd_tree(kset,10);
    }
};
```

The tree is declared in a different method of the class (and I use another class variable of type vec_arr that makes up the trees points). Now here is where I got lost in tracing the error. When I try to call the following method:

```
void test()
{
    double level = -0.3;
    std::vector<double> arr1 {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
    std::vector<double> arr2 {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
    vec3d vec1 {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
    vec3d vec2 {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
    vec3d vec3 {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
    vec3d vec4 {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
    vec3d vec5 {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
    vec3d vec6 {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
    vec3d vec7 {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
    vec3d vec8 {{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
    vec_arr vecarr1 {vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4, vec5, vec6, vec7, vec8};

    int N = 5;
    vec_arr  init_points;

    foo entity(N, level, kset);
    std::cout << entity.n << std::endl;
}
```

I get a segmentation error, that I figured must be due to the header for the kdtree structure. However, I fail to further trace it, because:

- doing the exact same things in the main method works perfectly fine, the error only arises when this is done elsewhere
- without accessing anything of the class instance, the code compiles just fine
- erasing any of the unused vec3d variables fixes the problem (as you can guess, I need them somewhere later in that method)
- Even with more member variables, sometimes erasing other member variables (like `level` or `n`) from the class fixes the problem
- using `new` to create the instance doesn't change anything
- getting rid of any of the member variables in the class fixes the problem (but I actually need them somewhere else in the project)

What is it that I'm overlooking? Is there some problem with the destructor in `KdVec3dAdaptor`? I'm sure it must be something dumb. Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting object which was not created. Look at destructor of `KdVec3dAdaptor` class. In `test` function you created `foo` object

```
foo entity(N, level);
```

in this constructor `my_kd_tree init_ps_tree;` member is created by using default constructor of `KdVec3dAdaptor` which didn't set `index` member. When `test` function ends, `foo` destructor is called and `init_ps_tree` is destroyed, but `index` was not set, and

```
delete index;
```

in `KdVec3dAdaptor` destructor crashes your program. In default ctor of `KdVec3dAdaptor` you should set `index` member to 0.

**EDIT**

I don't know why you leave definition of default constructor as

```
KdVec3dAdaptor() = default;
```

look at definition of `foo` constructor, before entering into body of foo ctor

```
{
    init_ps_tree = my_kd_tree(kset,10);   // [1] init_ps_tree was already created
}
```

object `init_ps_tree` was created by using default constructor (`index` member may contain junk data - random value, if this object is created as local variable). In this line [1] move assignment operator is invoked and below line will be executed

```
delete index;  // very dangerous
```

you can call `delete` on null pointer, but in your case we don't know what value `index` holds.
First, write ctor of `KdVec3dAdaptor` as

```
KdVec3dAdaptor::KdVec3dAdaptor() : index(0) {}
```

and next thing, in your move assignment operator you should use std::move to move vector data, now copy of vector is made.

```
    if (this != &other)
    {  // check that no self-assignment is performed
        delete index;
        index = other.index;
        m_data = std::move(other.m_data); // [2] this vector can be moved
        other.index = nullptr;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but are you sure that's the problem? I edited my post such that I actually do call the constructor (which I already did in my original code) of KdVec3dAdaptor in the constructor of my class, but the problem with the same weird behaviour persists. Edit: Indeed, it seems that setting index to the nullpointer in the default constructor fixes the problem, but why not the call to the normal constructor?

Comment: I think I know.. it's because I also delete the index in my move assignment operator, i.e. when I reassign the tree with a properly initialized one I still try to delete an object that was not created. Thank you very much !

Comment: Is there something else wrong with my move assignment operator? I don't know how to handle other.m_data to be honest. I'm having some weird problems there too...

Comment: thank you, but that "std::move" line results in another segmentation fault :/

Comment: `other` is temporary object, `m_data = std::move(other.m_data);` is fully safe, i think that this line is not the cause of segfault.